# use nested while loop to replace elements of list of lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop, nested-loops

I want to change the elemtents of an existing nested list with the output from this function

```
listoflist = [[None, None, None],[None, None, None]]

def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input
```

the output should be:

```
output execute() = 1

[[1, None, None],[None, None, None]]

output execute() = 4

[[1, 4, None],[None, None, None]]
```

**the task is not to use a new list**

the expected behavior of `insertdata` should be

data gets passed from `def _execute():` to `insertdata`

the existing values of the list are getting replaced one by one till each value is replaced

My aproach was a nested while loop with two counters for the row and the colum of the nested list: 
the main while loop start the second while loop
in the second while loop the values of the first row are getting replaced
if so the operation should proced to the next row

```
def insertdata(data):

    row_index = 0
    while row_index != len(listoflist):

       # inner loop
        data_added = False
        n = len(listoflist[row_index])
        index = 0

        while not data_added and index != n:
            if listoflist[row_index][index] is None:
                listoflist[row_index][index] = data
                data_added = True

            else:
                index += 1

            # gets not executed
            if index == n:
                row_index += 1
                break
```

the corrent behavior is that the first incoming value replaces all existing values of the list

so it looks like the second loop did not get restarted again to replace each value one by one

what am I missing here ?

full example:

```
"""
tasks



"""

listoflist = [[None, None, None],[None, None, None]]


def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input



def insertdata(data):

    row_index = 0
    while row_index != len(listoflist):

       # inner loop
        data_added = False
        n = len(listoflist[row_index])
        index = 0

        while not data_added and index != n:
            if listoflist[row_index][index] is None:
                listoflist[row_index][index] = data
                data_added = True

            else:
                index += 1

            # gets not executed
            if index == n:
                row_index += 1
                break

while True:
    insertdata(_execute())
    print(listoflist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done more simply with:

```
def _execute():
    user_input = input("type in: ")
    return user_input

def insertdata(lst, get_data):
  """ Inplace replacement of data in list 
      using function get_data """
  for row in range(len(lst)):
    for column in range(len(lst[row])):
      # Replacing items 1 by 1 
      # using function get_data
      lst[row][column] = get_data()

  return lst
```

**Test**

```
listoflist = [[None, None, None],[None, None, None]]

# id(..) shows the in memory address of an object
print(f'starting address listoflist {id(listoflist)}')
# Test routine placing result in dummy_list
dummy_list = insertdata(listoflist, _execute)
print(f'ending address listoflist {id(listoflist)}')
print(f'dummy list address {id(dummy_list)}')
print(f'listof list: {listoflist}')
print(f'dummy_list: {dummy_list}')
```

**Output**

```
 starting address listoflist 139769341482560
type in: 1
type in: 2
type in: 3
type in: 4
type in: 5
type in: 6
ending address listoflist 139769341482560
dummy list address 139769341482560
listof_list: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
dummy_list: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

We see that listoflist has the same ending and starting address (139769341482560), so we just mutated the list rather than creating a new one.

dummy_list has the same address as listoflist, so we returned the same list.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate over the arrays and place the data in?

```
for i in range(len(listoflist)):
    for j in range(len(listoflist[i]):
        listoflist[i][j] = data
```

Comment: I see you edited your question. Now it looks like you don't want all the values in the array to be the same, but to input them one by one. If so, you can use xbello approach